# Return ReportID on current running report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way to return either the ReportId/ItemId or even better the LogEntryId of an SSRS report on the report itself?  We're trying to create a reference to each report (there are numerous folders on report server) and I thought the best thing would be to use what's already available in the ReportServer DB.

I tried creating a dataset with the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [LogEntryId]
FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage]
ORDER BY TimeStart desc
```

and added a field to the report to return `LogEntryId` from this DataSet. I watched the table but the `LogEntryId` only seems to populate after the report has finished running. Am I asking for the impossible or is there another way?

Comment: Are you trying to reference the ID of the report, or of that instance of running the report?

Comment: More the instance which is why I'd love to get the LogEntryId and from there could retrieve more execution info is my thinking.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but I ended up creating a report number for every report and including that number in the name of the report (so we can search for it by by name in SSRS) and in the report title (so clients can say "it's report 12345"). Now I'm even getting fancy and adding a version number, like 12345.01.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear. Are you trying to make the report reference its own LogEntryID? This is not possible as the ID is not generated until the report runs. That said, you could get previous entries for the report and use that to provide statistics regarding that specific report.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want so then i could get the ReportID and query the exact parameters they used to run the report. The boss wanted to create a  spreadsheet with reference numbers we'd add to each report but I was hoping to use some info already created in ReportServer.  Guess I have one more thing to keep updated.  Thanks for your time.    Edit:  I know I can get the reportId but LogEntry would help with knowing that report ran and with what paramters at that time.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, but you can reference the parameters used in the current report and display them. As for making a spreadsheet, you can get the parameters that were used for any report ran in the [dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage] table. It would only exclude the report currently being ran which could be added to it for everything but the report ID. And depending on the frequency your SSRS is utilized, you could just get the max logentryID and add 1 to it assuming the current logentryID, although I don't know how tight the timings would be if 2 reports were ran at the same time.

Comment: "you could just get the max logentryID and add 1 to it".  I was actually going this route in the beginning but the possibility of multiple reports (same reports even) being ran across 100 clients is too great.